# How to speed up this update sql statment

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have this update that takes data from a view (upd_g307) that counts members in each family and put it in another table s_general
 Here is the update

```
Update s_general
Set g307 = (select upd_g307.county 
            from upd_g307 
            where upd_g307.id_section = s_general.Id_section 
              and upd_g307.rec_no = s_general. Rec_no
              and upd_g307.f306 = s_general.F306)
Where 
    g307 is null 
    and id_section between 14000 and 15000
```

This query is taking so long to run like half of an hour or even more! What should I do to make it faster?
I'm using oracle sql*

Comment: Did you tried running with explain? What's the problem in this query?

Comment: I edited my question :)

Comment: Please add the execution plan. And which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of statement is often faster when re-written as a MERGE statement:

```
merge into s_general
using (
  select county, id_section, rec_no, f306
  from upd_g307
  where id_section between 14000 and 15000    
) t on (t.id_section = s_general.Id_section and t.rec_no = s_general.rec_no and t.f306 = s_general.F306)
when matched then update 
    set g307 = upd_g307.county 
where g307 is null;
```

An index on `upd_g307 (id_section, rec_no, f306, county)` might help, as well as an index on `s_general (id_section, rec_no, f306)`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much this query is great it took almost no time!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [updatable join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11782) view in Oracle and I will take a look on the performance of the join anyway, because it is IMO the lower bound of the elapsed time you may expect from the update.

The syntax is a follows:

```
UPDATE (
SELECT s_general.g307, upd_g307.county 
FROM s_general
    JOIN upd_g307 on upd_g307.id_section = s_general.Id_section 
              and upd_g307.rec_no = s_general. Rec_no
              and upd_g307.f306 = s_general.F306
              and s_general.g307 is null
              and s_general.id_section between 14000 and 15000
)
set g307 = county
```

Unfortunately you'll get (with a high probability)

```
 ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

if the view `upd_g307`will be not found [key-preserved](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#i1006318)

You may or may not to resolve it defining a PK constraint on the source table of the view. As a last resort define a temporary table (it could be GGT) with PK constraint on the join key and us it instead of the view.

```
-- same DDL as upd_g307
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE upd_g307_gtt 
(Id_section number,
Rec_no number,
F306 number,
g307 number,
county number)
;
-- default -> on commit delete

ALTER TABLE upd_g307_gtt
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_upd_g307_gtt
PRIMARY KEY (id_section, Rec_no, F306);


insert into upd_g307_gtt
select * from upd_g307;

UPDATE (
SELECT s_general.g307, upd_g307_gtt.county 
FROM s_general
    JOIN upd_g307_gtt on upd_g307_gtt.id_section = s_general.Id_section 
              and upd_g307_gtt.rec_no = s_general. Rec_no
              and upd_g307_gtt.f306 = s_general.F306
              and s_general.g307 is null
              and s_general.id_section between 14000 and 15000
)
set g307 = county
;
```

Answer (score -1):

For MS SQL:

```
DECLARE @TEMP VARCHAR(50)
------------------------------------
select @TEMP=upd_g307.county 
from upd_g307 
where upd_g307.id_section=s_general. Id_section 
and upd_g307.rec_no=s_general. Rec_no;

------------------------------------------
Update s_general
SET g307=@TEMP
Where g307 is null and id_section between  14000 and 15000
```

or use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for better performance.

Comment: How do you know user3242425 is using SQL Server?

Comment: I am using oracle sql*